# Gstreamer configure not generating Makefile

Tags: makefile, gstreamer, configure

I need to compile Gstreamer from source, but the *configure* script is not generating the needed Makefile, *even though there seems to be no errors in the configuration step*. I've looked at *config.log* and the stdout output of *configure* (which I redirected to a *config.out* file), and none seem to point for any errors in the configuration step whatsoever. The configuration step even goes as far as to print a **configure: error: no** by the time it finishes.

The only thing pointing for a possible error is a **configure: exit 1** in the end of the *config.log* file, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on. For reference, I'm running a VBox virtual machine with 32-Bit Ubuntu 14.04. I'm also linking two pastebins with *config.log* and *config.out*. I've tried several versions of gstreamer, and I have the same issue with all of them.

Just as an observation, installing gstreamer from the Ubuntu packages is not an option, since I need to *specifically* compile the package.

config.log: http://pastebin.com/pSiLtyev

config.out: http://pastebin.com/g5jRPtpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the config log:

```
configure:21634: checking flex version /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4 >= 2.5.31
configure:21651: error: no
```

So, your version of Flex you have installed (which is 2.5.4) is too old (the script wants version 2.5.31 or higher).

I'll agree that whomever wrote this configure script did a poor job, since it doesn't make clear at all in the normal output that this is the problem.

Comment: Ohhh, damn. The first time I checked this line I thought it said configure:21634: checking flex version /usr/bin/flex version 2.5.4 >= 2.5.3.1. The next line also confused the heck out of me, since it seems like there is NO error. Well, thanks for the help!

Comment: Plus, there is no standard at all. Other missing libraries give different error messages. It was indeed quite a poor job.